# Parsing JSON Response Text Correctly

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have an issue in an Excel program I am creating. Put shortly, I have to pull JSON data from a website, parse it, and throw the response onto a worksheet for use later on. Whenever the code gets to the point where it is going to output the response text, the output is passing the first set of data I need from the response text. All data and examples below.

Code that creates and sends the HTTP request:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    URL = "REDACTED"

Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpRequest.send ""

Set Output = parse(httpRequest.responseText)

Pallet_Inv.Cells(1 + i, d) = Output.Item("result").Item("contains").Item(i).Item("resourceLabel")

Next
```

Pallet_Inv is the sheet the response text needs to output onto.
The "(1 + i, d)" is there as I have a header on the sheet the output is going to that I don't want overridden.

Code that parses the response text that returns from the request:

```
Public Function parse(ByRef str As String) As Object

   Dim Index As Long
   Index = 1
   psErrors = ""
   On Error Resume Next
   Call skipChar(str, Index)
   Select Case Mid(str, Index, 1)
      Case "{"
         Set parse = parseObject(str, Index)
      Case "["
         Set parse = parseArray(str, Index)
      Case Else
         psErrors = "Invalid JSON"
   End Select


End Function
'   skip special character
'
Private Sub skipChar(ByRef str As String, ByRef Index As Long)
   Dim bComment As Boolean
   Dim bStartComment As Boolean
   Dim bLongComment As Boolean
   Do While Index > 0 And Index <= Len(str)
      Select Case Mid(str, Index, 1)
      Case vbCr, vbLf
         If Not bLongComment Then
            bStartComment = False
            bComment = False
         End If

      Case vbTab, " ", "(", ")"

      Case "/"
         If Not bLongComment Then
            If bStartComment Then
               bStartComment = False
               bComment = True
            Else
               bStartComment = True
               bComment = False
               bLongComment = False
            End If
         Else
            If bStartComment Then
               bLongComment = False
               bStartComment = False
               bComment = False
            End If
         End If

      Case "*"
         If bStartComment Then
            bStartComment = False
            bComment = True
            bLongComment = True
         Else
            bStartComment = True
         End If

      Case Else
         If Not bComment Then
            Exit Do
         End If
      End Select

      Index = Index + 1
   Loop

 End Sub
 '
 '   parse collection of key/value
 '
Private Function parseObject(ByRef str As String, ByRef Index As Long) As Dictionary

   Set parseObject = New Dictionary
   Dim sKey As String

   ' "{"
   Call skipChar(str, Index)
   If Mid(str, Index, 1) <> "{" Then
      psErrors = psErrors & "Invalid Object at position " & Index & " : " & Mid(str, Index) & vbCrLf
      Exit Function
   End If

   Index = Index + 1

   Do
      Call skipChar(str, Index)
      If "}" = Mid(str, Index, 1) Then
         Index = Index + 1
         Exit Do
      ElseIf "," = Mid(str, Index, 1) Then
         Index = Index + 1
         Call skipChar(str, Index)
      ElseIf Index > Len(str) Then
         psErrors = psErrors & "Missing '}': " & Right(str, 20) & vbCrLf
         Exit Do
      End If


      ' add key/value pair
      sKey = parseKey(str, Index)
      On Error Resume Next

      parseObject.Add sKey, parseValue(str, Index)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         psErrors = psErrors & Err.Description & ": " & sKey & vbCrLf
         Exit Do
      End If
   Loop
eh:

End Function

Private Function parseKey(ByRef str As String, ByRef Index As Long) As String

   Dim dquote  As Boolean
   Dim squote  As Boolean
   Dim Char    As String

   Call skipChar(str, Index)
   Do While Index > 0 And Index <= Len(str)
      Char = Mid(str, Index, 1)
      Select Case (Char)
         Case """"
            dquote = Not dquote
            Index = Index + 1
            If Not dquote Then
               Call skipChar(str, Index)
               If Mid(str, Index, 1) <> ":" Then
                  psErrors = psErrors & "Invalid Key at position " & Index & " : " & parseKey & vbCrLf
                  Exit Do
               End If
            End If
         Case "'"
            squote = Not squote
            Index = Index + 1
            If Not squote Then
               Call skipChar(str, Index)
               If Mid(str, Index, 1) <> ":" Then
                  psErrors = psErrors & "Invalid Key at position " & Index & " : " & parseKey & vbCrLf
                  Exit Do
               End If
            End If
         Case ":"
            Index = Index + 1
            If Not dquote And Not squote Then
               Exit Do
            Else
               parseKey = parseKey & Char
            End If
         Case Else
            If InStr(vbCrLf & vbCr & vbLf & vbTab & " ", Char) Then
            Else
               parseKey = parseKey & Char
            End If
            Index = Index + 1
      End Select
   Loop

End Function
'
'   parse string / number / object / array / true / false / null
'
Private Function parseValue(ByRef str As String, ByRef Index As Long)

   Call skipChar(str, Index)

   Select Case Mid(str, Index, 1)
      Case "{"
         Set parseValue = parseObject(str, Index)
      Case "["
         Set parseValue = parseArray(str, Index)
      Case """", "'"
         parseValue = parseString(str, Index)
      Case "t", "f"
         parseValue = parseBoolean(str, Index)
      Case "n"
         parseValue = parseNull(str, Index)
      Case Else
         parseValue = parseNumber(str, Index)
   End Select

End Function
'
'   parse list
'
Private Function parseArray(ByRef str As String, ByRef Index As Long) As Collection

   Set parseArray = New Collection

   ' "["
   Call skipChar(str, Index)
   If Mid(str, Index, 1) <> "[" Then
      psErrors = psErrors & "Invalid Array at position " & Index & " : " + Mid(str, Index, 20) & vbCrLf
      Exit Function
   End If

   Index = Index + 1

   Do

      Call skipChar(str, Index)
      If "]" = Mid(str, Index, 1) Then
         Index = Index + 1
         Exit Do
      ElseIf "," = Mid(str, Index, 1) Then
         Index = Index + 1
         Call skipChar(str, Index)
      ElseIf Index > Len(str) Then
         psErrors = psErrors & "Missing ']': " & Right(str, 20) & vbCrLf
         Exit Do
      End If

      ' add value
      On Error Resume Next
      parseArray.Add parseValue(str, Index)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         psErrors = psErrors & Err.Description & ": " & Mid(str, Index, 20) & vbCrLf
         Exit Do
      End If
   Loop

End Function
'
'   parse number
'
Private Function parseNumber(ByRef str As String, ByRef Index As Long)

   Dim Value   As String
   Dim Char    As String

   Call skipChar(str, Index)
   Do While Index > 0 And Index <= Len(str)
      Char = Mid(str, Index, 1)
      If InStr("+-0123456789.eE", Char) Then
         Value = Value & Char
         Index = Index + 1
      Else
         parseNumber = CDec(Value)
         Exit Function
      End If
   Loop
End Function
'
'   parse string
'
Private Function parseString(ByRef str As String, ByRef Index As Long) As String

   Dim quote   As String
   Dim Char    As String
   Dim Code    As String

   Dim SB As New cStringBuilder

   Call skipChar(str, Index)
   quote = Mid(str, Index, 1)
   Index = Index + 1

   Do While Index > 0 And Index <= Len(str)
      Char = Mid(str, Index, 1)
      Select Case (Char)
         Case "\"
            Index = Index + 1
            Char = Mid(str, Index, 1)
            Select Case (Char)
               Case """", "\", "/", "'"
                  SB.Append Char
                  Index = Index + 1
               Case "b"
                  SB.Append vbBack
                  Index = Index + 1
               Case "f"
                  SB.Append vbFormFeed
                  Index = Index + 1
               Case "n"
                  SB.Append vbLf
                  Index = Index + 1
               Case "r"
                  SB.Append vbCr
                  Index = Index + 1
               Case "t"
                  SB.Append vbTab
                  Index = Index + 1
               Case "u"
                  Index = Index + 1
                  Code = Mid(str, Index, 4)
                  SB.Append ChrW(Val("&h" + Code))
                  Index = Index + 4
            End Select
         Case quote
            Index = Index + 1

            parseString = SB.toString
            Set SB = Nothing

            Exit Function

         Case Else
            SB.Append Char
            Index = Index + 1
      End Select
   Loop

   parseString = SB.toString
   Set SB = Nothing

End Function
```

The raw JSON data from the site:

```js
{"result":{"contains":[{"cptInMillis":1547531880000,"containerType":"Case
","cpt":"REDACTED
PM","stackingFilter":"REDACTED","associationReason":"-","isEmpty":"-","resourceLabel":"csXP25jMSzG","associatedUser":"REDACTED","cleanupAllowed":false,"isClosed":"-","containerId":"REDACTED","isForcedMove":"No","dwellTime":"REDACTED
: 1"},{"cptInMillis":1547531880000,"containerType":"Case
","cpt":"REDACTED
PM","stackingFilter":"REDACTED","associationReason":"-","isEmpty":"-","resourceLabel":"csXP25jMTHk","associatedUser":"REDACTED","cleanupAllowed":false,"isClosed":"-","containerId":"REDACTED","isForcedMove":"No","dwellTime":"REDACTED
: 2"},{"cptInMillis":1547531880000,"containerType":"Case
","cpt":"REDACTED
PM","stackingFilter":"REDACTED","associationReason":"-","isEmpty":"-","resourceLabel":"csXP25jMTN5","associatedUser":"REDACTED","cleanupAllowed":false,"isClosed":"-","containerId":"REDACTED","isForcedMove":"No","dwellTime":"REDACTED
: 2"},{"cptInMillis":1547445480000,"containerType":"Case
","cpt":"REDACTED
PM","stackingFilter":"REDACTED","associationReason":"-","isEmpty":"-","resourceLabel":"csXP25k9Z5F","associatedUser":"REDACTED","cleanupAllowed":false,"isClosed":"-","containerId":"REDACTED","isForcedMove":"No","dwellTime":"REDACTED
: 2"}],"endToken":null,"startToken":"0"},"ok":true,"message":""}
```

Now as some of the data is confidential, I have redacted it, however what I actually need I have left in place.

I need the "resourceLabel" object that is present in the JSON data I have added here.

Now I do get the data, however it starts outputting at the second "resourceLabel" object instead of the first.

What I need:

```
csXP25jMSzG  csXP25jMTHk  csXP25jMTN5  csXP25k9Z5F
```

What I keep getting:

```
csXP25jMTHk
csXP25jMTN5
csXP25k9Z5F
```

Now I could just be missing something obvious, but I am not sure why this keeps happening. If this question is too complicated, too long, or not explained enough, please let me know. Or if Stack is not the correct place for this sort of question, please direct me someplace else that would be.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Educated guess (as you miss the first value):`Output.Item("result").Item("contains").Item(i).Item("resourceLabel")`is zero-based, what means first item is `.Item(0)`not `.Item(1)`where you start.Change `.Item(i)`to`.Item(i-1)`

Comment: Can't test your code.  I get first error at `parseBoolean` since you don't include that. But there's a free JSON parser on [GitHub](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).  Of course, if your goal is primarily to write a JSON parser, that's not what you want.  But if your goal is to parse this particular JSON, the parser will work and it does return what you require.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: seems like this is the VBAJson ancestors code (Excel-Rest) and OP missed to provide the method and code origin by accident

Comment: your code has missing functions, class and variable declarations.

Comment: Yeah, I'm dumb. It's because the JSON response text was zero based, not 1. Changing from 1 To 100 to 0 To 99 fixed my problem. I guess it's been a long night. @ComputerVersteher: Yes, the code is legacy code from an older JSON parser, and I have been using this code with relative success for the past several months, though it is starting to show its age, and it does break occasionally, even on the same program pulling the same data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Thanks for the link, I will check that out and I might be able to go back and convert some older programs with this code. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: With the full [source parser code](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html) and updated for 64 bit in my case, I can get all items with the same basic structure as the answer given except I used syntax: For Each item In output("result")("contains"): Debug.Print item("resourceLabel"):Next . So +1 for existing answer.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks. Sometimes I "condense" my syntax as you did, but I did as I did to expose more of the structure.  Are there significant tradeoffs -- speed, efficiency, resources -- with the condensed vs expanded syntax?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I like your method due to readability and establishing clear variables for each stage. I suspect yours might be faster but don't know enough about internals.  I didn't know the parser mentioned so was fun to update to 64 bit only to find my end answer the same as yours (bar lazy syntax on mine). I guess you could test but doubt a big enough difference would be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your prime goal is to write a JSON parser, I would suggest using an existing JSON converter.  I have been using the one from [GitHub](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).  With that converter, it's relatively easy to get `resourceLabel`.  Here's one way:

```
Option Explicit
Sub pj()
    Dim strJSON As String
    Dim JSON As Dictionary
    Dim dRES As Dictionary
    Dim oContains As Collection
    Dim V

strJSON = Cells(1, 1).Value2
Set JSON = parsejson(strJSON)
Set dRES = JSON("result")
Set oContains = dRES("contains")

For Each V In oContains
    Debug.Print V("resourceLabel")
Next V

End Sub
```

With your JSON string in `A1`, the output:

```
csXP25jMSzG
csXP25jMTHk
csXP25jMTN5
csXP25k9Z5F
```